# Query not using index on timestamp without time zone field

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with more than 3 million rows, one column named `creationdate` is a `timestamp without time zone`.

I created a couple of indexes on it, like:

```
"idx_routingtasks_creationdate" btree (creationdate)
"idx_routingtasks_creationdate2" btree ((creationdate::date))
```

When filter by `creationdate::date` (casting by date) the index `idx_routingtasks_creationdate` is not used:

```
explain analyze select * from routingtasks where creationdate::date < (now() - interval '1 day')::date;                                                                                 
                                                             QUERY PLAN                                                             
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on routingtasks  (cost=0.00..1315631.93 rows=2811638 width=715) (actual time=186642.012..413763.643 rows=2800659 loops=1)
   Filter: ((creationdate)::date < ((now() - '1 day'::interval))::date)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 212248
 Planning time: 0.195 ms
 Execution time: 413875.829 ms
(5 rows)
```

The same when not casting by date:

```
explain analyze select * from routingtasks where creationdate < now() - interval '1 day';
                                                            QUERY PLAN                                                             
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on routingtasks  (cost=0.00..1300588.39 rows=2918447 width=715) (actual time=72089.312..327288.333 rows=2876756 loops=1)
   Filter: (creationdate < (now() - '1 day'::interval))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 141052
 Planning time: 0.104 ms
 Execution time: 327401.745 ms
(5 rows)
```

How can I create an index on the `creationdate` column to allow this filter use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer lies in this part of the execution plan:

```
Seq Scan ... (actual ... rows=2876756 ...)
  ...
  Rows Removed by Filter: 141052
```

Since almost all rows are returned anyway, using a sequential scan and discarding the few rows that are filtered out is the most efficient way to process the query.

If you want to verify that, temporarily

```
SET enable_seqscan = off;
```

to make PostgreSQL avoid a sequential scan if possible. Then you can test if query execution gets faster or not.